# Is there a portal that can help to share the content of my web page to Facebook, Twitter, etc?

Tags: asp.net, share, addthis

The requirement is for each of my product page, add a bar which allows users to share the current product to Facebook, Twitter, Linked In, etc.

Is there a common tool that can help to do so? (ASP.net based), or we should do this one by one?

Any suggestion is welcomed, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Use the [addthis](http://www.addthis.com) tool it will contain all

Use of  http://www.gigya.com